# Monitoramento de script SQL

Tags: sql, email, pl-sql, notificação, monitoramento

Galera alguém pode me ajudar,

Na minha empresa tenho um script que verifica quantos emails foram processados e enviados pelo servidor, porem algumas vezes o programa que faz os envios trava e só fico sabendo que travou por que meus usuários reclamam que não esta chegando e-mail,

Ai vou no script e altero para ele processar novamente e restarto o programa que faz os envios

Minha duvida é "Teria algum programa que verifica-se esse script e quando analisa-se esse SQL veria que faz 10 minutos que os emails não foram processados e me notifica-se"

Comment: Se você utilizar servidor linux, pode criar um script em php que verifique se no seu banco de dados quando foi o ultimo envio e te mandar um e-mail dependendo das condições que você quiser. Depois é só agendar o script para rodar de 10 em 10 minutos pelo crontab.

Comment: Você poderia desenvolver seu próprio programa, como ja tem a consulta montada, é apenas desenvolver um programa que envia um alerta ao detectar os 10 minutos. Também é importante saber o motivo desses travamentos, para resolver esses problemas.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, vou tentar desenvolver em PHP, mas não tenho conhecimento para conectá-lo com o Oracle, to em busca disso, mas muito obrigado pelas dicas, então esse programa é do nosso fornecedor do sistema ERP, ja verificamos de tudo pra saber pq esta parando mas ate agora nada, acreditamos ser o servidor que esta ficando defasado e acaba travando o programa, mas como a grana ta curta aque, temos que buscar outros caminhos kkk

Comment: @VictorMansolelli utilize `oci_connect` para utilizar Oracle com PHP, mas procure por Zabbix (uma solução profissional).